# OneTone WP Theme - Adjust Background Vide Size

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using the "OneTone" theme from MageeWP on Wordpress. I'm trying to alter the CSS code to change the video background from full screen to half screen.

I did the following:

```
#tubular-container{
     height: 550px !important;  /* My edit */
   position:absolute!important;
 }
```

This is a decent work around, it pulls up the second section so it COVERS half the video, I was wondering if anyone knows the exact CSS section to actually CHANGE the video size. THANKS!!

Code is too big to paste but this is a very very popular FREE theme on Wordpress. Link to the site is here: https://wordpress.org/themes/onetone/

Comment: Please post the URL you are working on or the code within which it is wrapped.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/themes/onetone/

Comment: http://www.battery-park.us